# Javascript validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that people can click and add fields to the form and I need to have it validate the values in those fields if it is clicked.

So say I click it twice and get the 2 separate sets of fields and I need the rotation % to make sure it equals 100 at the time of save.

I have put in this function to get it to validate on the save and everything works except if I edit a different form that doesnt have any fields in it.
 I am trying to see what the easiest way would be to check and see if the fields are on there or not so I can check them.

Here is my code:

```
function audit()
{
    var totalsum = 100;
    $( '[name="rotation\\[\\]"]').each(
      function()
      {
        totalsum -= ($(this).val() * 1);
      }
    )
    if(totalsum > 0){
        alert("Your rotation % does not equal 100");
        return false;}
    return true;}
```

---

```
$('.add_creative img').click(
function(){
    $.post( '/json/ad_creative/',
    { action: "add_creative", this_brand_id: $("[name='this_brand_id']").val(), adtype: $( '.new_run [name="adtype"]').val()},
    function(data){
        if( data.result ){
            $('.add_creative').append(data.html)
            }    
        },
        'json'
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/YW4Sv/

(if you have some working code, i can expand it to your needs)

JS:

```
function audit() {
    var totalsum = 100;
    $('.rotation').each(function() {
        totalsum -= ($(this).val() * 1);
    })
    if (totalsum != 0) {
        alert("Your rotation % does not equal 100");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


$('.add').click(function(){
    $(this).before($('<input>', {class: 'rotation', name:'rotation[]'}));
    return false;
});

$('#theForm').submit(audit);
```

HTML:

```
<form id='theForm'>
    <button class='add'>ADD FIELD</button><br/>
    <button>SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Mine is very similar to this but what I have trouble with is that when they edit the form it will run this audit function and since I am setting the variable and saying if it != 0 then call that alert. I am trying to make sure it passes the function if there are no rotation fields and if there are make sure to run through it.

Comment: @MikeJones can you please put up an example of what you are talking about to a jsfiddle or to a paste?

Comment: @MikeJones. whatever your issue is. i have no idea what ur doing to create the fields, i could be doing something completely different!

Comment: @Neal - added the code to my above example to add the fields on my form

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the jquery validation plug-in will help.  Sorry if you have already looked at this.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: that will only partially work, since Mike not only needs to validate the existence or content of a field, but also if their sum is 100.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a flag in the beginning that is set to false.  ie: haveFields = false.  Once, the user adds a field, then it'll be true, then you can perform validation based on that.

Comment: These are database driven fields so wont happen in the same time but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

select only the fields belonging to your form, something like:

```
$('#id_of_the_form input[name^="rotation"]')
```

this will select of the input fields that start with rotation for the form with the id "id_of_the_form"

here more info about the jquery selectors:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

I second @tuuk79

But I would put out there that the documentation on the developers site really isn't all that good...  This is what I used when learning Validate.  I also whole heartedly urge you to stick with validate because once you learn it, it'll make your life so much easier!

http://www.ferdychristant.com/blog//articles/DOMM-7LZJN7 //article detailing how to *really* use validate.
http://www.ferdychristant.com/blog//pages/jQuery%20validation%20code
http://randomactsofcoding.blogspot.com/2008/10/starting-with-jquery-how-to-write.html
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression

There is also an amazing depth of information simply in... http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation ...you just gotta click through it all! :)